# iOS- protocols and delegates on the example

Tags: objective-c, ios4, delegates, protocols

Ok, i was searching but there wasn't any method that was working for me. Following code bases on many tutorials and Apple documentation, but i can't get it to work. Can anybody help please?

Code is crashing at: obj.delegatee = self; (in class B.h), also methods respondsToSelector and performSelector:withObject aren't recogized.

I want to set delegate object, on which there will be a method called when we tap on particular picture.

class A.h:

```
@interface AViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>{
    id delegatee;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <AViewControllerDelegate> delegatee;
@end

@protocol AViewControllerDelegate
@optional
- (void) tappedImage:(int)tag;
@end
```

class A.m:

```
@dynamic delegatee;
- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[gestureRecognizer view];
int a = imageView.tag;

if ([self.delegatee respondsToSelector:@selector(tappedImage:)])
    [self.delegatee performSelector:@selector(tappedImage:) withObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt:a]];
```

}

class B.h:

```
#import "AViewController.h"
@interface BViewController : UIViewController <AViewControllerDelegate> {...}
```

class B.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
//... some code

AViewController *obj = [[[AViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
obj.delegatee = self;
}

- (void) tappedImage:(int)tag{
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d.png",tag]]];
CViewController *NView = [[CViewController alloc] initWithPicture: imgView.image];
[self presentModalViewController:NView animated:YES];
[NView release]; NView = nil;
}
```

Many thanks for any help, i hope it will help me to understand how protocols work.

Comment: You sure you want that @dynamic? My guess is you want @synthesize instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two things.

1. (Your Crash) You declared your `delegatee` as @dynamic instead of @synthesized which means you are responsible for creating the `-(void)setDelegatee:(id<AViewControllerDelegate>)` (and the getter) method. Fix: Simply change it from `@dynamic` to `@synthesize delegatee;`
2. (Your warnings) Whenever you want to call methods that you do not explicitly define in your protocol, then your protocol will need to conform to another protocol :). Fix: Add the `NSObject` protocol to your decleration.

`@protocol AViewControllerDelegate<NSObject>`

Comment: Yes! This was the matter, thank you very much for such deep explanation with example! You just fixed my headache ^^

Comment: However my tappedImage method inside class B is never called.. Can you see and tell why..?

Comment: Make sure the delegatee is not nil at this point and also change the protocol signature to take NSNumber instead of int, using performSelector:withObject: will actually pass an unexpected* value to the method. *(the pointer address of the NSNumber)

Comment: Well it is nil (0x0) however i thought it was already set in class B (viewDidLoad) where i did: AViewController *obj = [[[AViewController alloc] init] autorelease]; obj.delegatee = self;. This class was loaded, and i saw that this command is called and obj.delegatee is set to self (which is not nil).. Why then i still have nil?

Comment: Time to set up break points and find out whats is and is not getting called at the right times :) fun stuff, you may need to post another question if you narrow down your problem and still need some help.

Comment: Yeap, i'm doing it at the moment ^^ Thank you very much for all the help!

Comment: AViewController *obj = [[[AViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
obj.delegatee = self; obj wasn't passed to class A. I had to declare it in classB.h and then send it to class A using dvController.delegatee = obj.delegatee;

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that using `@dynamic delegatee` requires you to implement `-(id)delegatee` and `(void)setDelegatee:(id)delegatee`.