# Controlling a button text from another view

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton

I have two views and i used two view controllers. From the main view i want to initialize the button in the second view with a certain text.

If I press the button in the second view, then i can store that button reference to a global UIButton, and change the text then onwards.

But the very first time, how can I initialize the button text in  the second view from my main view with a particular text ?

Answer (score 2):

You should not do that: every controller should be responsible for its own view. Full stop.

You can always set some poperty on the second controller and use it when the second view appears on the screen to change whatever you like.

Comment: This is the easiest way to do it. Just keep one `NSString` property in second view controller and in main view controller assign that property to desired value and on second view's view will appear method assign that property to button's title that's it.

Comment: @Anton. good input. I will do that. But how do i "initialize" button text every time the view is loaded with different text. Should I do that in viewDidLoad ? or call an init function ? But how to access the property of the button in the init fuction or viewDidLoad etc ? I can easily do that when the - (IBAction)buttonAPressed:(UIButton *)sender method because I have the access to the button object. but from the init how to get the reference to the button.

Comment: When -viewDidLoad is invoked, the outlets are already initialized, so you can write something like: [self.myButton setText:self.myTextProperty forControlState:UIControlStateNormal] in -viewDidLoad. However, it might be more appropriate to invoke this in -viewWillAppear: (in case you would re-use the controller instance) - it is called AFTER viewDidLoad anyway, so the outlets are set there as well.

To sum up: just set up an outlet in controller, connect it to a button and set the text in -viewDidLoad or -viewWillAppear:

Comment: @Anton, Bingo... the key is, i should create an outlet and map the button. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you use delegates & @protocol to access other class [example](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html),

[refer ex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903712/ios-protocols-and-delegates-on-the-example), [ex1](http://www.tekritisoftware.com/ios-customized-protocol-iphone-development), [link](http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/03/19/simple-objective-c-protocol-example/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you did this. But if you post some code, it will be helpful. If you already have the above code working, then you need to have the following in order for what you are expecting to work.

Say you have ViewControllerA, ViewControllerB as the two view controllers. You can definitely initialize the text in the button when you create the XIB file.

But I am assuming that you want to do this programatically. If you want to access a button in another view controller, you need

a. Access to the other view controller.
b. Once you have access to the other view controller, access to the UIButton variable in that view controller.

So you can do the following in the ViewControllerA code,

```
-(void)changeButtonTextOfVCB{
        viewControllerB.button setTitle:@"MyTitle" forControlState...
 }
```

and you can have a button in viewControllerA, which will trigger the above method.

Having said this, I am not sure whether you have the whole thing working, where you can even switch between the view controllers

Answer (score 0):

If you make a button in FirstViewController and want to change button properties like title..etc from the second view, then you should make properties in SecondViewController

```
  @property (nonatomic,assign) UIButton *button;
```

when you navigate firstViewController to secondViewController just pass the button Object like

```
obj = [SecondViewController alloc]...]
obj.button = button;//(FirstViewController button object)
```